# Are job recruiters subject to the do-not-call-list law? (the FTC regulation)

Tags: recruitment, legal, law

This is in regards to US law. I know that if I register my phone number on [www.donotcall.gov](http://www.donotcall.gov), it's illegal for telemarketers to call me to advertise products or services. What about job recruiters who mass call people advertising/offering jobs? Are they also subject to this regulation?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would be covered by [the legal definition of telemarketing](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-16/chapter-I/subchapter-C/part-310/section-310.2#p-310.2(gg)) in the Telemarketing Sales Rule, but I am not a lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

The do-not-call list is only for telemarketers making sales calls.  It's right there on the same site you mentioned.

I don't put my personal phone number on my resume, for this exact reason.  Better to use a disposable number only when I'm job hunting, and when I find a job, I cancel the number.

Comment: And how are recruiters trying to sell you a job (or their services) not telemarketers?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well, in general you can't *buy* a job and if the recruiter isn't trying to get you to pay them then they probably don't count as a telemarketer. In this case, the recruiter isn't trying to get you to buy something, they're trying to get you to *do* something. I could call someone up and try to 'sell' them on the idea that they should walk or bike to work instead of driving but unless I also try to get them to buy some sneakers or a bike, that isn't telemarketing no matter how annoying it is.

Comment: @BSMP That really depends on how the law is specified and the jurisprudence. In any case, marketing doesn't imply that you need to buy something. Trying to get you to switch jobs or use their recruitment services is also a form of marketing, as is promoting a healthy lifestyle.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am not a lawyer but the [legal definition](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-16/chapter-I/subchapter-C/part-310/section-310.2#p-310.2(gg)) does use the phrase "...induce the purchase of goods or services or a charitable contribution...". Maybe OP will re-ask this on Law SE.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, this more for a lawyer, and I agree that on the face of it, likely recruitment doesn't fall under this law (though there is a form of exchange of services and money, so who knows...).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the regulation doesn't seem to have been written with unsolicited recruiters in mind, as there is really nothing in it that applies to your situation.

> **11. What is an Exempt Organization?**
>
> ...
>
> **Business-to-Business Calls:**
>
> Most phone calls to a business made with
> the intent to solicit sales from that business are exempt from the Do
> Not Call provisions.
>
> https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/qa-telemarketers-sellers-about-dnc-provisions-tsr

Now, I'm not saying you're a business, but if recruiters are calling you, they could argue that they're calling you to solicit **your** services and **your** sales so to speak.

In my case, I made the mistake to put my phone number on my online resume for less than 24 hours, so in a way, I did solicit phone calls from potential recruiters and potential employers, and I was inundated with phone calls from recruiters who did keyword searches, but who didn't bother to read my resume (or perhaps, who didn't understand my resume), so I do empathize with your annoyance.

In my case, it took two years for those recruiting phone calls to stop. My recommendation is for you to take the call and say that they have the wrong number, and that this is a new number for you. In my opinion, they're much more likely to correct their database if they believe their target is no longer there.

In the future, I'd suggest you use a free Google Voice account. It's great for many reasons and highly configurable. I'd also suggest you use a disposable email address as well.

The harsh truth is that anyone with an internet connection and a computer can be a recruiter these days. The barrier to entry is extremely low. And with globalization, this effect has only been compounded by the differences in currency and wages between nations.

Now this doesn't mean that all recruiters are bad, it just means that you need to be very selective about the ones you interact with.

Comment: A recruiter calling a prospective employee with a job offer, or trying to get them to sign up with them is not a business-to-business call.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I agree, but there is really nothing else in the regulations that even comes close. Again, my point is that this regulation really wasn't written with recruiters in mind. It just seems too narrow to me.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the regulation (I'm not from the US), but I guess recruiters will be considered sales people (they are basically trying to sell you a job, or their services), and thus are not exempt from such rules.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Again, I completely agree with you. In my book, recruiters are salespeople. But unfortunately, the laws in the United States do not always use common sense.